# How to specify which type of webpack loader for which type of parent file the assets is loaded into?

Tags: webpack

I want to use the file loader for svg assets that are loaded into CSS, but I want to use the react-svg loader for svg assets loaded in to JS. It doesn't seem that this is possible...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can set an `issuer` condition on any webpack `Rule` to use different loaders for different "parent files".

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      oneOf: [
        {
          issuer: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
        {
          issuer: /.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'react-svg-loader',
        },
    },
  ],
}
```

More info in the docs
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-issuer

Answer (score 0):

You can define `file-loader` to be default loader for SVG files in `webpack.config.js` and then use `react-svg-loader` in `require` statements. Loader configuration in webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: {
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: { name: '[name].[ext]' }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then use loader in `require` statements in your JavaScript files:

```
import React from 'react';
const Icon = require('!!react-svg-loader?es5=1!../../../assets/svg/icon.svg');

export default function(props) {
    return (
        <div>
          <Icon />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that double exclamation marks (`!!`) is used here to prevent using file loader that we defined in config file.